# Get a url paramater value from a post method laravel php

Tags: php, laravel, url

Hi for example I have this link:

```
http://localhost/fp_site/public/form/create?ssid=4
```

In there, I have a form which has a post method. Is it possbile if I could also get the `ssid=4` in the URL in my post method like so

```
public function store(Request $request)
{

    var_dump(Input::get("ssid")); exit;
    $rules = array(
        'fname'               => 'required',
        'lname'               => 'required',
        'phonenumber'         => 'required',
        'address'             => 'required',
        'postcode'            => 'required',
        'email'               => 'required',

    );

    $validator = Validator::make(Input::all(), $rules);

    if ($validator->fails())
    {
        return Redirect::to('form/create')->withErrors($validator);
    }
    else
    {
        $form = new Form;
        $form->fname          = Input::get('fname');
        $form->lname          = Input::get('lname');
        $form->phonenumber    = Input::get('phonenumber');
        $form->address        = Input::get('address');
        $form->postcode       = Input::get('postcode');
        $form->email          = Input::get('email');
        $form->save();
        Session::flash('alert-success', 'Form Submitted Successfully.');


        return Redirect::to('form/create');
    }

}
```

The reason I have that in my url is that I have multipe sources that will help me for the traffic in my website. And in my form I want to get the `ssid` value in the URL so that I know from whom the traffic came from and save it along with the data.

Answer (score 2):

I think you could define the route for the form process like this:

```
 Route::post('form/create/{ssid}', 'YourController@store');
```

Then, in your controller, get the parameter in this way:

```
public function store(Request $request, $ssid)
{
     dd( $ssid );

    //other code...
}
```

Comment: Can't be I'm using resource controller. Anyway I found a solution to it :) I just made a javascript function that will get the parameter value and put that value in a hidden field :)

Comment: yes, using a hidden field could be another solution

Answer (score 0):

Found a work around on it. I just made a javascript function that will get the parameter value on load and put that value in a hidden field inside the form :)

Comment: the solution by @Moppo is better one. Creating a javascript function and putting that value in a hidden field seems like a too much of work to me.

Comment: @MilanMaharjan Yes indeed it's easier but mt route is already configured. I have a resource route for forms. If changes my route that will put me in work work and codes than just adding a hidden field and few lines of javascript.